# Calling Method from Other Class Does Nothing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have one class called MainMenu, which has a method called switchViews, with 2 parameters, an NSWindow and an NSView.

I then have the AppDelegate, which i want to use this method in the 'applicationDidFinishLaunching'.

So in the AppDelegate.h i have imported the MainMenu.h and in the AppDelegate.m I use as follows:

```
MainMenu *theMainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc]] init];
[theMainMenu switchViews:param1:param2;
```

There are no warnings or errors, it just doesn't call the method.

If i copy and paste the method instead of calling it, it works fine so it's not a problem with the variables, it seems there is just an error running the method if it's in a different class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

switchViews method:

```
- (void)switchViews:(NSWindow*)mainWindow:(NSView*)newView {
    NSView *dummyView;
    [theMainWindow setContentView:dummyView];
    [theMainWindow setContentSize:newView.frame.size];
    [theMainWindow setContentView:newView];
}
```

EDIT: sorry guys, it was just a typo.

SOLUTION: I was using the wrong parameter in the method call. Below is the working code:

```
- (void)switchViews:(NSWindow*)mainWindow:(NSView*)newView {
    NSView *dummyView;
    [mainWindow setContentView:dummyView];
    [mainWindow setContentSize:newView.frame.size];
    [mainWindow setContentView:newView];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the switchViews method declaration?

Comment: @J_D edited post to show method :)

Comment: Are you sure that this code compiles? I would expect your method to be declared like: - (void)switchViews:(NSWindow*)mainWindow andView:(NSView*)newView { ... }

Comment: yes, there was a typo in the init statement, corrected now

Comment: @J_D: The method name is syntactically valid, though stylistically unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> MainMenu *theMainMenu = [MainMenu alloc[ init]];
> ```

If that's your code, then it isn't even running, because the build fails, because that code is invalid.

Assuming your *actual* code doesn't contain syntax errors, nothing happening generally means you sent a message to `nil`. Either `-[MainMenu init]` returned `nil`, or the implementation of `switchViews::` tried to send a message to an object it doesn't have.

Assuming you don't have any statements in `-[MainMenu init]` to return `nil`, the latter case is more probable. Make sure that it creates whatever objects it needs to, or, if you mean for it to be nib-based, make sure that you have hooked up all of your MainMenu object's outlets and that you didn't forget to load the nib.

Edit:

> ```
> - (void)switchViews:(NSWindow*)mainWindow:(NSView*)newView {
>     NSView *dummyView;
>     [theMainWindow setContentView:dummyView];
>     [theMainWindow setContentSize:newView.frame.size];
>     [theMainWindow setContentView:newView];
> }
> ```

You named the method's first argument variable `mainWindow`, but then you send messages to `theMainWindow`.

If the MainMenu object has an outlet named `theMainWindow`, make sure that that's hooked up, and remove the redundant first argument. Alternatively, kill off the outlet (or whatever `theMainWindow` is) and use `mainWindow`.

Also, since the AppDelegate (for some reason) is passing the window to the MainMenu object, make sure the AppDelegate actually has the window. Start by checking the value of “`param1`” in the AppDelegate code.

Comment: you did it, i confused myself with mainWindow and theMainWindow variables. I changed the variables to the correct ones and it worked straight away. Thanks v much for finding this mistake. Second time you've helped me!

Comment: Note that this is still a bad design;  that method has no dependency on the state of the `MainMenu` instance and instantiating an instance of said class just to do a single operation like that really doesn't make much sense.  Typically, there would be a singleton MainMenu that'd float around your app.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't compile(or, if it does, it isn't doing at all what you want).

This makes no syntactic sense:

```
MainMenu *theMainMenu = [MainMenu alloc[ init]];
```

In general, though, you probably don't want to be allocating & initializing a *new instance* of something that is most likely *already instantiated and on the screen*.

Reading between the lines, I suspect you would benefit from brushing up on both the foundations of Object Oriented programming and on Cocoa design patterns.